# how 1 +"2" works in C#

Tags: c#, operators, type-safety

I was reading about the type safety in C# like how we can't assign an integer value to a bool etc., which made me to do some experiment.

I executed a code snippet hoping that it will give a compile time error but it worked and provider a result.

```
var add = 1 + "2"; // it gave 12 as result in C#
```

[image]

Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect and please share any document link explaining this in brief.

Comment: For the record, you could have simply moused over the `+` operator in code to see how it was actually defined. You would have seen that it was interpreted as the operator overload with `object` and `string` operands. If you had placed the caret immediately before the operator and pressed F1, the relevant documentation would have been opened in your browser. This sort of Help has been a feature in VS and Windows for many years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This compiles simply because there is a `+` operator declared, that takes any `object` as the first argument, and a `string` as the second argument.

The [langauage specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12105-addition-operator) says:

> The predefined addition operators are listed below. For numeric and enumeration types, the predefined addition operators compute the sum of the two operands. When one or both operands are of type `string`, the predefined addition operators concatenate the string representation of the operands.
>
> [...]
>
> String concatenation:
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
> string operator +(string x, object y);
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> These overloads of the binary `+` operator perform string concatenation. If an operand of string concatenation is `null`, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-`string` operand is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type object. If `ToString` returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.

In your case, operator overload resolution would select the third overload in the above list. It is equivalent to `1.ToString() + "2"`.